# How bindValue for table name?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bindvalue

Is it possible to do a bindvalue for the table name? mine doesn't seem to pick it up basically the second 2 binds work fine if I remove the :table and add the tablename instead, but I want to use this for more than one table from the same form.

The field for table on the form is defined from a result of the previous query so the table name appears on the form in a value as $table which displays correctly so this should post the value of $table to the table bind???

```
try {
    $sql = 'UPDATE :table SET
                archive = :archive
                WHERE id = :id';
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindvalue('table', $_POST['table']);
    $s->bindvalue('archive', $_POST['archive']);
    $s->bindvalue('id', $_POST['id']);
    $s->execute();
}
```

Comment: What did you get after trying?

Comment: I can't quite follow that post that you just pointed me if the direction of @Akam

Comment: Fortunately it's not possible. PS: use white list of the allowed tables and just substitute it as a string

Answer (score 1):

Since prepared statements are a "bit" more than `sprintf`, it doesn't make sense to set the table by variable.

A prepared statement is passed to the DB before the actual values are set. So the DB may look for a way how to answer the query. After this preparation the actual values searched for are set. The query is answered, when `execute()` is called.

So, to prepare "a way how to answer the query" (as I called it), the table name is a significant information. That is why it does not make sense to pass it as a variable. That is also why it doesn't work.

So, you have to string concatenate the table name:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE '. $table .' SET
            archive = :archive
            WHERE id = :id';
```

As @zerkms suggest, you should whitelist the possible table names.

Comment: for Clean Code You Can use variable with a string literal :
$sql = "UPDATE {$tableName}"